# Minimize the maximum difference

Tags: python, arrays, greedy

I'm trying to solve this [Problem](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/minimize-the-maximum-difference-between-the-heights/) from GFG with following approach:

```
class Solution:
    def getMinDiff(self, arr, n, k):
        # code here
        arr.sort()
        min_diff = arr[-1] - arr[0]
        if min_diff <= k:
            return min_diff
        
        min_ele = arr[0] + k
        max_ele = arr[-1] - k
        if min_ele > max_ele:
            min_ele, max_ele = max_ele, min_ele
            
        for i in range(1, n-1):
            curr_min = arr[i] - k
            curr_max = arr[i] + k
            
            if curr_min >= min_ele or curr_max <= max_ele:
                continue
            
            if max_ele - curr_min <= curr_max - min_ele:
                min_ele = curr_min
            else:
                max_ele = curr_max
                
        return min(min_diff, max_ele - min_ele)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    tc = int(input())
    while tc > 0:
        k = int(input())
        n = int(input())
        arr = list(map(int, input().strip().split()))
        ob = Solution()
        ans = ob.getMinDiff(arr, n, k)
        print(ans)
        tc -= 1
```

But i'm unable to pass the testcases:

```
Input:
4
10
6 1 9 1 1 7 9 5 2 10

Its Correct output is:
5

And my Code's output is:
6
```

I'm unable to figure out fault in my logic or code. Could some suggest corrections or better approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm unable to figure out fault in my logic or code.

As per your current logic, you decide to add or subtract k just based on the current element. But it might not yield the min diff overall. For example, for 5 you decided to add k and it resulted in the range `(5,11)` for the whole set. Rather if you have subtracted it would have yielded `(1,6)`.

---

> Could some suggest corrections or better approach?

**Approach:**

- Sort the array
- Lets handle the trivial case, `if k > (max - min)` then directly return `max - min`. Since adding k to min and subtracting k from max will yield a larger difference. (To be precise, `2 * k + (max - min)`)
- In all other cases, we will add `k` to min element and subtract `k` from max element. There should exist an index in the array, where we switch from adding k to subtracting k. The below diagram shows the switch index:
  [image]

*(Note: In the diagram, `B`can be less than `D` and also `A` can be greater than `C`)*

- Now we iterate over the array and at each index, if it was the switch index we determine the range.

  - From the diagram, we can calculate the range as below

    - if `A < C` then the range will start with `A` or else with `C`
    - Similarly if `B > D` then the range will end with `B` or else with `D`
- The min `range` across all index gives the result

---

**Updated Code:**

```
def getMinDiff(self, arr, n, k):
    # code here
    arr.sort()
    min_diff = arr[-1] - arr[0]
    if min_diff <= k:
        return min_diff
    
    for i in range(0, n-1):
        if arr[i + 1] < k :
            continue
        start = min(arr[0] + k, arr[i + 1] - k)
        end = max(arr[-1] - k, arr[i] + k)
        min_diff = min(min_diff, end - start)
            
    return min_diff
```

**Explanation:**

- In the for loop, we determine the switch index range for each element as follows

  - Start: From the diagram minimum of `A` and `C`. Here `A` is `arr[0] + k` and `C` will be `next element - k` i.e,. `arr[ i + 1 ] - k`
  - End: Maximum of `B` and `D`. `B` is `current element + k`, i.e., `arr[i] + k` and `D` will be `arr[-1] - k`

Comment: could you plz elaborate 3rd point in ur approach. Also i understood the concept of switch case but where is it used in ur code?

Comment: Also why i+1 for start and i for the end

Comment: @777_mahakaal, made a few updates. Pls check if it clarifies?